# Email REGEX checking on email format

Tags: javascript, regex

```
export const REGEX_EMAIL = /^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/;

I want to check email format like
email : Heythere123@something.com // passed
but 
email: Heythere123@something.com2222 // should not pass
email: Heythere123@something.com#$@! // shuuld not pass
```

//but from now they pass
How  i add the REGX email format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had created this function for my projects:

```
 isEmailValid(email) {
       const regularExpression = /[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]{2,3}/;
       return regularExpression.test(email);
  },
```

I use this site to test them:
https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

Using `\S` is a very broad match and matches any non whitespace char.

You can make the pattern slightly more specific using a character class at the end `[a-z]{2,}$` and not match an @ sign twice using a negated character class `[^@\s]`

```
^[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[a-z]{2,}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/scnTxO/1)